# Formula for adding decrementing numbers to a sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need a formula that, if 5000 is inputted, it will result in 1, and if 5000 + 4999 is inputted, it will result in 2, and so on, until 5000 + 4999 + 4998... + 1 is 5000. Is there an formula for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a terribly nice one: $$F(x)=\frac {10001-\sqrt {100020001-8x}}2$$

works.

This follows from the observation that your specified values are $$F\left(5000n-\frac {n(n-1)}2\right)=n$$

which leads to a quadratic equation in $n$.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly for my purposes.